# Apache Require all granted in general config file

Tags: apache, virtualhost

im trying to configure the access for a subdirectory in my virtual host.

After some try and error i got to the conclusion that the directive Require all granted over the /var/www directory in the apache.conf file is applying to my specific virtual host configuration file, where i use Require valid-user.

So when i request the file the server applies both Require clauses and do an require any operation over them, so the Require all granted makes all users authorized to see the resource, even when i specified a restriction in the specific config file for my virtual host.

Is there any way to override this behaviour without touching the general config file?
I want to keep the Require all granted an AllowOverride None over the /var/www folder.
Thank you.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Thats the file with the AllowOverride none and the Require all granted.

Comment: you can use a `.htaccess` file to override the `Require` directive and place that `.htaccess` file directly in the subdirectory

Comment: I tried it, but it still applies the .htaccess configuration merged with that required all granted of the apache config file

Comment: Have you allowed for the settings to take effect with the `AllowOverride All` in the apache config for the subdirectory, otherwise the `.htaccess` won't take effect